# Trying to generate prefabs over and over in semi-random positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made this code in an effort to start making a script that generates bush objects in my scene randomly, however when in runs it only spawns the first bush.  Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BushSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bush;
    private float x = 0f;
    private float y = -.47f;
    private float z = 0f;
    private int bushCount = 0;
    private Vector3 origPos;
    private bool xPlus = false;
    private bool xMinus = false;
    private bool zPlus = false;
    private bool zMinus = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        SpawnBushes();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void SpawnBushes()
    {
        Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        Instantiate(bush, startPos, Quaternion.identity);
        bushCount += 1;
        while (bushCount < 100)
        {
            Vector3 checkPos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
            Collider[] intersecting = Physics.OverlapSphere(checkPos, 1f);
            if (intersecting.Length == 0)
            {
                //code to run if nothing is intersecting as the length is 0
                Instantiate(bush, checkPos, Quaternion.identity);
                bushCount += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //code to run if something is intersecting it
                RollPos();
            }
        }
    }
    void RollPos()
    {
        if (xPlus == true
            && xMinus == true
            && zPlus == true
            && zMinus == true)
        {
            int newRoll = Random.Range(1, 4);
            if (newRoll == 1)
            {
                x += 10f;
            }
            else if (newRoll == 2)
            {
                x -= 10f;
            }
            else if (newRoll == 3)
            {
                z += 10f;
            }
            else if (newRoll == 4)
            {
                z -= 10f;
            }
            xPlus = false;
            xMinus = false;
            zPlus = false;
            zMinus = false;
        }
        else
        {
            int roll = Random.Range(1, 4);
            if (roll == 1)
            {
                if (xPlus == false)
                {
                    x += 2f;
                    xPlus = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RollPos();
                }
            }
            if (roll == 2)
            {
                if (xMinus == false)
                {
                    x -= 2f;
                    xMinus = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RollPos();
                }
            }
            if (roll == 3)
            {
                if (zPlus == false)
                {
                    z += 2f;
                    zPlus = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RollPos();
                }
            }
            if (roll == 4)
            {
                if (zMinus == false)
                {
                    z -= 2f;
                    zMinus = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RollPos();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried putting SpawnBushes in Update to run while a bool is true then make it false when SpawnBushes is done, but that creates the first bush, then 99 other bushes in one random position next to it.

If someone can point me in the right direction or tell me I'm completely off-base I would appreciate it immensely!

Comment: *then 99 other bushes in one random position next to it.* is that to say 99 bushes in the *same* position?

Comment: Yes in the same position.  The bushes each have colliders but no rigidbodies

Comment: does the bushcount ever reach 100 or does it get stuck in the loop?

Comment: bushcount does reach 100 and spawns 100 bushes when its in update, but the position of the bushes stops changing after the first position change

Comment: What is `RollPos()` supposed to do? Select a random position for the prefab? It should be noted that `Random.Range(1, 4)` will never return `4`, so you are only selecting 1-3. Then `zMinus` will never be `true` and the first section of your `if` statement in `RollPos` will never run.

Comment: does it reach 100 in the code you have posted?

Comment: Ron Beyer got it, cant believe I didnt notice that.  Also had to put make all the bools false when a bush instantiated.  Thanks Ron!

Answer (score 1):

Ron Beyer pointed out that I didn't have a large enough range in my Random.Range in RollPos().  Thanks again Ron!